# Is it "following up on" or "following up with"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which of the following sentences would be correct?

1. I am following up **with** a purchase.
2. I am following up **on** a purchase.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase "follow up with" is used for someone.
Example : You should follow up with him later.

"Follow up on" is used for something.
So, you can use "I am following up on a purchase."